# Git / SourceTree: how to delete a branch?

Tags: git

Following git flow, I have merged my finished feature branches into develop branch. But then I've created the release branch to soon accidently. What I'd like to do now is go back into the develop branch (where the feature merge has happened, f250065) and delete the release branch.

I can't delete the release branch because I'm currently on it.
When I try to check out f250065 I would create a headless state.
I don't want to finish the release either currently because I don't want to merge it into master.

How to proceed ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by checking out f250065 and immediately creating a new feature branch (and checking out). Then I could delete the release branch and merge the new feature back into develop.